# failed jsonArrayRequest

Tags: android, arrays, android-volley

MY function content to make jsonArrayRequest is:

```
    JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.POST,
            FilesUsed.url_display_thought, null,
            new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                    try {
                        JSONObject jsonObject1 = response.getJSONObject(0);
                        JSONObject jsonObject2 = response.getJSONObject(1);
                        if (jsonObject1.getBoolean("error")) {
                            ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
                            list.add(jsonObject2.getString("message"));
                            displayThought(list);
                        } else {
                            int count = 0;
                            ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
                            while (count < response.length()) {
                                try {
                                    JSONObject jsonObject = response.getJSONObject(count);
                                    String thought = jsonObject.getString("post");
                                    list.add(thought);
                                    count++;
                                } catch (JSONException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                            }
                            displayThought(list);
                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            error.printStackTrace();
        }
    }) {
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
            params.put("email", "sainiakshay04");
            return params;
        }


    };

    RequestHandler.getInstance(this).addToRequestQueue(jsonArrayRequest);
```

The content of the php it is using is:

```
require_once '../app/display_personal_account.php';

$response=array();

    if(isset($_POST['email'])){
        $db = new display_personal_account($_POST['email']); 

        $res=$db->get_info_added("shared_content");
        if($res==1){
        $response=$db->display_shared_content();}
        else{
            $response[]['error']=true;
        $response[]['message']="No Content To Display ";}

    }

    else{
        $response[]['error']=true;
        $response[]['message']="ERROR: INVALID REQUEST";
    }




echo json_encode($response);

?>
```

but the output it is displaying is ERROR:INVALID REQUEST, although I'm binding email using getParams, isset of php is not working and going to else part.
HELP!

Answer (score 0):

You're checking `isset($_POST['email'])` but you send `null` parameter in the JsonArrayRequest.

For now, JsonArrayRequest only supports the JsonArray parameter.

There are two things that you need to do :

1. Send the email in the JsonArray parameter

   ```
   JSONObject request = new JSONObject();
   request.put("email", userEmail);

   JSONArray arrayParam = new JSONArray();
   arrayParam.put(request);

   ....

   JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.POST, 
       FilesUsed.url_display_thought, arrayParam, ...
   ```
2. Get the email in the PHP

   ```
   require_once '../app/display_personal_account.php';

   $response=array();

   $inputJSON = file_get_contents('php://input');
   $input = json_decode($inputJSON, TRUE);

   if(isset($input[0]['email'])){
       $db = new display_personal_account($input[0]['email']); 

       ....
   ```

After that, you should just work fine :)